# Screen off animation similar to Android Gingerbread?

Tags: screensaver

Just curious, but I love the look.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Lv1p4TvRw4

Is there something similar to this for Ubuntu, when shutting down, or logging out, or even when the screen goes to sleep?

Comment: This might be best implemented as a Compiz plugin.

Comment: it would be interesting to know how they implement it on android, given android is a flavour of linux, it might be easy (ish) to port it.

Comment: hmm., Android x86 might provide the clues

Comment: @Slipstream android is more than just a flavour of linux. It runs applications (most of em) on a virtual machine, so it wouldn't be so easy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such compiz plugin in existence, but if you have C++ skills, or know someone who can take a try at it, it would be relatively easy to write such a plugin or extend one of the existing plugins to produce this animation.

There is a similar animation for compiz in the git repository (I think it was part of "simple-animations"). It would have to be ported to C++ and then modified to work on login or logout.